# laravel array required validation every fired event value is exists?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

below id my validation code.

```
$rules = [
    'other_feature[]' => required
];

$message = [
     'other_feature[].required' => 'The other feature field is required.',
];

$this->validate($request, $attributes_validation, $attributes_message);
$result = $this->UploadRepo->updateUploadValue($data,$id);
```

in other_feature pass multiselect value like.

```
<select name='other_feature[]' multiple>
   <option>First</option>
   <option>Second</option>
   <option>Third</option>
   <option>Four</option>
   <option>Five</option>
</select>
```

where I create a mistake in validation why empty validation is fired every time even I select value please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should drop the `[]` it's useless. On the request you just get an array of multi selected options so you don't need to leave the brackets there. What you can do is to validate is it array.

```
$rules = [
    'other_feature' => 'required|array'
];

$message = [
     'other_feature.required' => 'The other feature field is required.',
];
```